# Is it possible in rails to return response and keep processing the data the client submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have a webservice that processes user submitted data. The user doesn't need to receive a response based on that data, he just needs to submit it. However, I do need to process that data. Currently the processing takes place directly as a response to the post action, and after the processing, it return a statuscode. This normally takes 0.5s - 2s, but sometimes much longer, when a user submits a lot of data.

Is it possible in Rails to spawn a new thread for processing that data, while returning the status code (and thus finishing the request for the user)?

Comment: Any reason not to do it asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resque, Delayed Job, or Sidekiq should suit your needs.

You can find links to these three, and a couple more here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs

Answer (score 2):

I think you can process data in background, using something like [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `fork` - Its not an elegant solution but it gets the job done and introduces no extra moving parts. To do that fork over the entire rails app ( pretty messy but the rails app serving the request will respond immediately ) and have the process detached:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def heavy_lifting
    process = fork do
      # calculate PI or process input
      # ...
      # sends the kill signal to current Process, which is the Rails App actually calculating PI
      Process.kill("HUP") 
    end
    Process.detach(process)
    # respond here
  end
end
```

**Keep in mind**
Although your processing/job might only need a few megs of memory to run, `fork` allocates as much memory as the parent process does. Here is a good [summary of what fork generally does](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).

**Update - Same thing with threads**

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def heavy_lifting
    Thread.new do
      # calculate PI or process input
      # ...
      Thread.kill
    end
    # respond here
  end
end
```

Comment: So, it's not possible to simply in the controller to do something like `Thread.new{do_something(@data)}` ?

Comment: sure you can use threads aslong as you dont `#join` them back and properly kill them.

Comment: @krichard Somehow, here, the controller is waiting for the forked block to finish to send back the response. Can this depend on the server settings?

Comment: @oldergod One server problem you could have would be a single core processor. Fork and threads will not help if you are on a single core processor as they will still run one at a time.

Comment: Threads will fulfill the purpose of this question, which is returning a response and process other data in a separate thread, so it will actually help. In a single processor you can run only one thread at a time, that's nothing new. Forks will take advantage of Copy-On-Write, which means that only memory pages that are the same for both processes stay shared. So the statement that says that "fork allocates as much memory as the parent process does" is not true or not always true.